# get checked event data binding wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I created a textbox ,a passwordbox and a toggle button in wpf. I need,when I checked the button,the password to be visible, and when the button is unchecked the characters are shown as bullets. My problem is , when I run the application, the button is unchecked (this means hidden password) ,but the password is still shown. Just after I checked the button,everything works as I want. How can I make to binding from start? Not only after I checked it

XML code:

```
   <ToggleButton  Name="toggle1" Height="40" Padding="0" Width="56" Canvas.Left="131" Canvas.Top="0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" IsChecked="{Binding ShowPassword}">
```

code:

```
public bool IsPasswordVisible
    {
        get { return _IsPasswordVisible; }
        set
        {
            if (_IsPasswordVisible == value)
                return;
            _IsPasswordVisible = value;
            if(IsPasswordVisible)
            {
                passwordBox1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
                textbox1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                textbox1.EditValue = passwordBoxEdit1.Password;
            }else{
                passwordBox1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                textbox1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
                passwordBox1.Password = textEdit1.Text;
            }
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ShowPassword"));
        }
    }       

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = this;

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    #region OnPropertyChanged
    /// <summary>
    /// Triggers the PropertyChanged event.
    /// </summary>
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set IsPasswordVisible to false after seeting datacontext

```
this.DataContext = this;
IsPasswordVisible = false;
```

remove below code from IsPasswordVisible setter

```
if (_IsPasswordVisible == value)
                return;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do most of it using xaml only with bindings and converters.

Example:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <BoolToVisibilyConverter x:Key="boolVisibilityConverter"/>
    <BoolToVisibilyOppositeConverter x:Key="boolVisibilityOppsiteConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid x:Name="myGrid" Margin="5" Width="500">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Visibility="{Binding ShowPassword, Converter={StaticResource boolVisibilityOppsiteConverter}}"/>
        <PasswordBox Visibility="{Binding ShowPassword, Converter={StaticResource boolVisibilityConverter}}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

[Converters](http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html):

```
class BoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return bool.Parse(value.ToString()) == true ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed; 
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}

class BoolToVisibilityOppositeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return bool.Parse(value.ToString()) == false ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed; 
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Then, the toggle button should only be binded to the `ShowPassword` property.

when setting `ShowPassword` , copy the text from the text box to the passwordbox and vice versa.

```
public bool ShowPassword
{
    set
    {  
       if (_IsPasswordVisible == value)
            return;
        _IsPasswordVisible = value;

       if (_IsPasswordVisible = true)
          textbox1.EditValue = passwordBoxEdit1.Password;
       else
          passwordBox1.Password = textEdit1.Text;

       if (PropertyChanged != null)
           PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ShowPassword"));
    }
```

This way, `TextBox` and `PasswordBox` visibilty is binded to the `ShowPassword` property. since it's default value is false and they set thier initial visibilty from there, this should fix your problem

Comment: but just toggle button is binded ..I will try your solution,I hope it works. Thank you!

Comment: @alexAlex you are right, your toggle button is binded correctly. no need to change that.

Answer (score 1):

It is just because in toggle button default for IsChecked is null.

```
public Nullable<bool> IsChecked { get; set; }
```

Comment: but he's binding that value to his property. Can you elaborate your answer? how should the OP resolve the issue?

Comment: So need to make sure that "ShowPassword" dependency property must be nullable.  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378894/wpf-togglebutton-ischecked-binding-issue)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try setting the Password box to be collapsed by default? Everything else should just work as normal.